# Increase speed of API calls osx

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire

I want to make my API calls as fast as possible using swift. I know that using Alamofire helps with speed but is there anything faster than using Alamofire? I am creating trading software so every millisecond makes a huge difference. These are "post" and "get" requests I am making to execute the trades. Right now there is a lot of variability in the speed of the calls. I know there are platforms like neumob that speed up applications so I wanted to know if there were any concepts like that which I can apply to my application. I am developing it using swift and it will be run on OS X.

I am also using a websocket to get order book data. To connect to the websocket, I am using Starscream. If there is a better way to connect to the socket I would love to know that as well.

Comment: First rule of improving performance is to measure performance before attempting to make it faster.  Before attempting to optimize the code path that you think is slow, first validate where the most time is being spent.  There are tools that will show you time spent across individual functions (inclusive and exclusive). Use that to guide you on what to optimize. As for network perf improvements, that's a whole other discussion. But you will probably want to get Charles/Fiddler traces to see how your application is spending doing network I/O. Could be the server....

Comment: Alamofire does not have anything to do with speed actually.

Answer (score 1):

If milliseconds matter, you shouldn't be using HTTP. Or even TCP. AFAIK, most trading applications use stream connections of some kind, usually transmitting protobufs instead of JSON, so events come in as fast as they're sent over the wire. Barring that, using `URLSession` directly may be a few instructions faster than Alamofire, which wraps `URLSession`, but I doubt it would make a noticeable difference. As far as an HTTP connection goes, `URLSession` is pretty damn fast, as that's what Safari and the rest of the system use.

Comment: If milliseconds matter than the most important thing is having a dedicated physical connection anyway.

Comment: Right. I assumed the question was asked because that wasn't possible (i.e. this is for an app, not a trading backend).

Comment: This is for a os x app. We are trading crypto so we don't have much control over the API that is being used on the exchange's side (i.e. binance). Can we use AFAIK with binance?

Comment: @Nevin Basically your initial assumptions are wrong. If you are not implementing an automated decision software with a physical connection then milliseconds, even hundreds of milliseconds won't matter. Your app will be slowed by user actions and by the actual API calls, both creating delays up to multiple seconds.

Comment: @Sulthan I am implementing an automated decision software so this has nothing to do with a user's actions

Comment: Do you know if increasing the speed of our internet connection will make a significant difference? The package sizes are so small that I feel like it won't make a difference right? Or am I completely wrong here? I get a ping of about 3 ms right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is very likely I/O bound, not CPU bound, so the main bottleneck will be your internet connection and the data that it transmits.

If you cannot change the communication protocol because you do not control the API server, the only thing you can do is to run your app in a data center that is geographically close to the API server. As long as the service requires you to use HTTP and web sockets, you can't go much faster than NSURLSession, Alamofire or Starscream without years of optimization.

If you can control the API server, you could switch to plain TCP or even UDP. Then you could come up with a custom communication protocol that uses small binary messages.

---

Of course, you have to profile first and actually find out, which parts of your code are slow. There may be other code that takes a few milliseconds to run.

Comment: so if we increase the speed of our internet connection, will that make a big difference?

Comment: I cannot give a definitive answer to that. Maybe yes, if the latency of the connection is the major bottleneck. Geographical distance may also play a role, as light traveling through a fiber at 0.6*c takes ~20ms around the globe. Maybe the API server itself can have much bigger latency that is not the same for all users, so this may have no benefits at all.